# Communication between javascript client and java server

Tags: javascript, java, websocket, communication

I want to create a js code that permit from every browser where it's running to open socket with a java server and send receive data(string) between us, i googled a lot i have found technology like node.js or DWR but they can still help me.

Comment: you can use simple Ajax call. If you looking for any framework you find lots more. Search on google.

Comment: why don't you use java code as a web service from js?

Comment: Any web application framework should do the trick. (i.e. Apache Struts)

Comment: i have solved the problem i will use websockets for the comunication between mine java and javascript program thanx all for the comments